# Why does Windows Update download updates for 32-bit Win 7 when I have 64-bit and how to solve it?

Tags: windows-7

I have my Windows Update set to "I'll choose when to install" instead of updates installing automatically; good thing too because 90% of the updates are for 32-bit systems!  Am I suppose to install them?  Shouldn't I only install 64-bit version  updates?  And, how to I make Windows Update download the proper updates only?

Side question: Is there a way to "unselect all" in the Windows Update app?

Win 7 64-bit.
IE 8.

Comment: Screenshot please.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a screenshot app.

Comment: printscrn, paste in paint. Else windows 7 has the snipping tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 64bit system, you still (most likely) have all the 32bit components anyway.

Your system can run both 32bit and 64bit applications. So you need to have all Windows components in 32bit and 64bit. If updates are released for those components, you'll have to update both 32bit and 64bit.

Some components might actually not exist as 64bit at all. So you get only a 32bit version on your 64bit system.

If you want to make sure Windows Update only downloads the packages you really need, then don't mess with it and let it do its thing. It, most likely, is doing the right thing already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the computer should only be showing and selecting 64bit updates.  On my 64bit windows 7 system every marked (for bits) windows update item shows "For x64bit-based systems".  Even if there are 32bit parts, both 64bit and 32bit items come in "for the 64bit system".  How to fix it ? why is it not? There must be some registry item it looks at.

Go to the device manager and see if "computer" shows a 64bit "computer driver" or not.  I do not know where else to look yet.

To unselect/select all, in the Columns line is an extra checkbox, clicking that selects all or unselects all.

[image: Select All]

If that was happening on my win7 machine, because of the way the component store items are put in, and the updates files, I would scratch the whole install and start over, mostly to save space.